# Force PHP to not include/require certain files

Tags: php, include, require

Is there a way of forcing PHP not to include/require(_once) certain files?

I'm developing with a local testing clone of a large PHP project that runs on a group server. To speed up this clone, I would like to prevent PHP loading certain 'add-on' files that I don't need in my local test clone, but that we do need on the server.

So is there some way of preventing PHP from ever loading these files?

Comment: yes, comment them out...

Comment: @DanielMorgan Yea, comment out lines from few hundreds of files. Go ahead.

Comment: @ElonThan, well surely it makes the most sense? the amount of time he will spend searching/waiting for answer it would be faster to comment them out.

Comment: @DanielMorgan So there is no sense in looking for right way to achieve something?

Comment: @ElonThan considering the fact that they have to be included for when it goes on a server anyway, no, not really.

Comment: (this conversation is confusing me now...) I can't comment them out, as then when my changes are sync-ed to the server, the comments would be included too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that springs to mind, although horrible, is as follows:

- Change the include path with set_include_path() such that it looks in a specified directory before the '.' entry (and indeed before any other include paths you rely on). You'd naturally only want to do this for your local environment (based on a domain name, IP address, env var, etc. check).
- Create (on the fly or otherwise) those files you don't want to be included as blank files

The files will still be included but processing time is negligible given than the files don't have any code to be parsed.

Comment: or better, set it for a large project where not everything is routed via a single php file in a `.htaccess` (or `.user.ini`)

Comment: Will this work if the paths of the `include()`s are set absolutely?

Comment: Sadly not, no. Include paths only apply to relative paths. In theory, if the files referenced as absolute on the development platform aren't required then you can just blank them on that platform as one would assume they're not part of your app's source tree.